# Can I combine a constantsearchquery with a phrase query into a booleanquery in lucene?

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch, text-search

Can I have a `BooleanQuery` which has two other queries, one `SHOULD` and one `MUST`? I want the `SHOULD` query to be of type `ConstantScoreQuery` and the other of type `PhraseQuery`.

I know `PhraseQuery` actually contributes to the overall score but `ConstantScoreQuery` won't contribute. Is that true?

How will the results be arranged if `ConstantScoreQuery` is along with other types of queries in the `BooleanQuery`?

Comment: NOTE: you typed in "constantsearchquery" but the actual query class is (likely) `ConstantScoreQuery` as the former class doesn't even exist.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I think we need to retain the exact names of classes and other aspects of code on StackOverFlow - got it!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213964/if-wildcardquery-doesnt-affect-the-scoring-of-documents-why-does-it-return-0-5), [ConstantScoreQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/ConstantScoreQuery.html) contributes a constant to the overall score.  All matches get a constant boost from it, non-matches get no boost from it.

If the `ConstantScoreQuery` is a required search term, it doesn't contribute meaningfully to score (All documents returned by the overall search will have the same score boost from it), but it does still contribute to scoring.

As far as how the results will be arranged "along with other types of queries", that's really too vague to be meaningfully answered.  Perhaps you would benefit from the [Lucene documentation on scoring](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/package-summary.html#scoring).