# If WildcardQuery doesn't affect the scoring of documents, why does it return 0.5 constantly?

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch, text-search

I am using a WildcardQuery on documents and I see that the result documents all of them have a score of 0.5. I read that queries like WildcardQuery do not affect the scoring of documents and now I am wondering what is the cause of the score to be 0.5.

I am using this simple query:

```
WildcardQuery wq = new WildCardQuery("filed_name", "book");
```

Comment: Did you try to run your query with explain=true flag to see how different parts of your query affect the final score? Could you post the result list with explain information and your query here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WildcardQuery` certainly **does** affect scoring.  It uses a [`CONSTANT_SCORE_AUTO_REWRITE`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiTermQuery.html#CONSTANT_SCORE_AUTO_REWRITE_DEFAULT), which may be what you are referring to.  That means that fields that match the WildcardQuery each have a equal boost to the score added by that match.  There is, however, none of the typical Similarity logic (tf-idf, for instance) applied for the WildcardQuery's matches.